# Fetch data from MySql to C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, while-loop

I have a `MySql` table from which I fetch data to my `C#` application. Randomly some data are inserted in this table form another source. I want to fetch those data continuously in my `C#` application. My DB connection and select query are following :

```
string connection = "Server=localhost;Database=intel;Uid=root;Pwd=";
        MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        MySqlCommand selectData;
        dbcon.Open();
        selectData = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        selectData.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, user_name,user_type FROM win_user ORDER BY user_id ASC ";
        MySqlDataReader rdr = selectData.ExecuteReader();
```

I want to execute my select query unit it get any data.

```
if 
  Get data = null
```

*execute my select query again*

```
else 
 Get data = data
```

*execute my next code*

I think it can be happen with while loop, but I dont know how ? Can any onk help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do sounds odd but, to answer the question as asked, you can use a loop like so:

```
MySqlDataReader rdr = selectData.ExecuteReader();

// Check whether the result set is empty.
while (!rdr.HasRows)
{
    rdr.Close();

    // Pause before trying again if appropriate.

    rdr = selectData.ExecuteReader();
}

while (rdr.Read())
{
    // Read data here.
}
```

Comment: Its working. But problem is that I want to fetch data continuously, I mean suppose I get 5 row first time and its execute successfully, in the mean time or later database get another 5 row from another source. With this code my application dont read those data. So I need to execute those 2 while loop again and again . But how can I do that ?

Comment: How would you do anything regularly?  Use a `Timer`.  I'm not aware of anything in MySQL that will notify you when data becomes available so you have to poll and the way you generally do that in a GUI app is with a `Timer`.

Comment: MySql dont notify me that why I am trying to pull data continuously when it get data it will process.So I need a recursive function which call the select command again and again after process previous data .

Comment: No you don't need a recursive function.  This is no place for recursion.  You would either use a loop, a `Timer` or a combination of both, depending on the circumstances.  Definitely no recursion.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
If(rdr.HasRows)
{
    rdr.Read();
    // do your logic
}
rdr.Close();
```

use rdr.Read() only when you have some data in datareader object.
if you simply want to read values without checking null than use this

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    // do logic
}
rdr.Close();
```

this loop runs as many times as no of rows exist in your select query result.

Comment: There's no provision in there to requery if the result set is empty.